# autoconf: continue after package check failure

Tags: automake, autotools, autoconf

In my configure.ac script, I have a basic check for X11:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(X11, x11 > 1.6.4, [AC_DEFINE(HAVE_X11)], [])
```

If this fails, I still want to continue. I thought since I added a blank field in the failure condition, it would continue. However, I still get errors:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (x11 > 1.6.4) were not met:

No package "x11" found
```

How can I write this line so that it continue if the package is not found?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the blank command to a noop solved the problem:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(X11, x11 > 1.6.4, [AC_DEFINE(HAVE_X11)], [:])
```